# Github Actions workflow for pushing a container to Github Container Registry fails with "unauthenticated"

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-container-registry

I want to build and push a docker container from my Github repsitory to the Github Container Registry. Maybe it's worth mentioning that the repository lies in an ogranization.
Here is my Github Action workflow:

```yaml
name: <name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - server

jobs:
  login:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: create image from repository
        run: docker build -t ghcr.io/${{ github.actor }}/<img-name> .
      - name: push image to GitHub Container Registry
        run: docker push ghcr.io/${{ github.actor }}/<img-name>:latest
```

The `login` passes, but the `build` fails with the following error:

```
The push refers to repository [ghcr.io/<user>/<img-name>]
2059ea815744: Preparing
8e3db2b6bb5e: Preparing
5aaeefe84632: Preparing
908e917b0525: Preparing
dff5b20a51e8: Preparing
407c3ac1f7e9: Preparing
e12889c39beb: Preparing
8d3ac3489996: Preparing
e12889c39beb: Waiting
8d3ac3489996: Waiting
407c3ac1f7e9: Waiting
denied: unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I looked up many solutions but none worked. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the docker login is in one job and the build, push actions are in a different job. For each job, a separate GitHub runner is run and once it is finished, it exits. Furthermore, unless specified by the `needs` key, jobs are by default considered independent and are run concurrently anyway so the build, push run sequentially in your workflow and login takes place in parallel on a different GitHub runner. To make your workflow run, modify the code as follows:

```yaml
name: <name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - server

jobs:
  dockerloginbuildpush:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: create image from repository
        run: docker build -t ghcr.io/${{ github.actor }}/<img-name> .
      - name: push image to GitHub Container Registry
        run: docker push ghcr.io/${{ github.actor }}/<img-name>:latest
```

So now you login, build your image and push successfully since you are logged in on the  machine you are pushing on.

Comment: thanks, that makes more than sense and is the correct answer, sadly I'm getting another (unrelated?) error when pushing: ```denied: permission_denied: The requested installation does not exist.```

Comment: In the last step, write `docker push ghcr.io/${{ github.actor }}/<image-name>` and don't put `latest` tag. See if that works.

Comment: I found the fix: since I was in an organization, I replaced all ```${{ github.actor }}``` with the org. name, it works now, thanks Brad